# Is it possible to list AWS Lambdas from one Lambda application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have several application in AWS Lambda console and there are many Lambdas in each of my application.

Is it possible to retrieve Lambdas from one application using API?

There is [Lambda.Client.list_functions](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.list_functions) in boto3, but seems like it's unable to filter by Lambda application.

[image]

Comment: What is a "Lambda application"? Are you referring to SAM?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I've attached screenshot from AWS console

Comment: I think this user is referring to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/deploying-lambda-apps.html

Comment: Looking at the Service clients ref docs  - like Java and .NET - there is no methods - such as getApplications - that i can see.

Comment: I wonder if it would be [`list_applications()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/serverlessrepo.html#ServerlessApplicationRepository.Client.list_applications) from the `ServerlessApplicationRepository`?